# Optimize for two drivers - Google Maps Directions API

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I am wondering is there a way of using the waypoints parameter (google maps api) with the optimize argument to suggest two routes instead of one (for example for two drivers that might be equally splitting the deliveries).

Or using a different API altogether... (I am interested in total time and order of the waypoints)

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the guides on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in order to better understand your question and provide you with even better answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use waypoints in order to get multiple routes out of one directions API request. The API will return a route that goes through all waypoints. However, the API is capable of showing alternative routes if you set alternatives to true in the request object. If alternative routes are returned they will also go through all waypoints though. If you want to split waypoints between multiple drivers, you will need to make multiple directions requests and include only the waypoints each driver will need to reach when making each request.

Also, Setting optimize to true in the request will not yield two routes, it will allow the directions service to re-arrange the waypoints in a more efficient order.

I'll also link you to the directions API documentation so that you can reference it:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

I hope this helps!